# JQuery Validation : Fail if two fields both optional are filled out?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that I am trying to validate that has two fields both optional:

```
<label><b>URL Webcam Image:</b></label>
<p></p>
<input type="text" name="photo" id="photo" class="input"  />
<p></p>
<label><b>Upload</b></label>
    <br/><span>JPG, max. 200 kb</span> 
 <input type='file' name='uploaded_file' id="uploaded_file" /> 
<p></p>
```

Validation should fail if both fields are filled out and should be ok instead if  only one of this fields is filled or both fields are empty
I can't find a method with Jquery validation to make this.. All that i have found is with required condition but i don't want it fot this two fields

Comment: Are you going to validate on form submit?

Comment: yes i have a form with other fields and rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to write a new custom rule.

```
$.validator.addMethod('notBoth', function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || ($(element).is(':filled') && $('[name="' + param + '"]').is(':blank'));
}, "you must leave one of these blank");

$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        foo: {
            notBoth: 'bar'
        },
        bar: {
            notBoth: 'foo'
        }
    } 
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/uv23hgr7/**

You'll also need to use the [`groups`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) and [`errorPlacement`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) options to consolidate the two error messages in to one and place it within your layout.

Answer (score -2):

This checks if both imagedata fields have values. If there is only one filled out, the real submit is triggered:

```js
    var orig = $('#uploaded_file').get(0).outerHTML;
    window.validatePic = function () {
        valid = !($('#photo').val() && $('#uploaded_file').val());
        if (valid) {
            $('#realSubmit').click();
        } else {
            alert('Please choose only one image.');
            $('#photo').val('');
            $('#uploaded_file').after(orig);
            $('#uploaded_file').remove();
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>... other form options
    <br>
    <br>
    <label><b>URL Webcam Image:</b>

        <label />
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="photo" id="photo" class="input" />
        <p></p>
        <label><b>Upload</b>

            <label />
            <br/><span>JPG, max. 200 kb</span> 
            <input type='file' name='uploaded_file' id="uploaded_file" />
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" onclick="validatePic()">Submit</button>
            <button type="submit" id="realSubmit" style="display: none">hidden</button>
</form>
```

Comment: OP was looking for solution using the jQuery Validate plugin.